# Adjust the datatables filters correctly with diferent words

Tags: jquery, regex, datatables

I have a datatable with several columns.
One of them is id=event

To filter by "Event" I release a modal with a multiple select2 (id=event_filter) and by clicking on the Send button (id=filter-button) I launch the following code by javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
let table = $('#datatable-table').DataTable();
$('#filter-button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let str = $('#event_filter').find(':selected').map(function() {
        return $( this ).text();
    })
        .get()
        .join( "|" );
    if (str.length > 0){
        console.log(str);
        table
            .columns($('th#event'))
            .search(jQuery.fn.DataTable.ext.type.search.string(str),true,false  )
            .draw();
    } else {
        table
            .columns($('th#event'))
            .search("")
            .draw();
    }
  })
})
```

Among the select options are:

-Natal

-Pre Natal

-Post Natal

The problem is: When I select ONLY Natal, the console.log (str) returns Natal, but the table filters Natal, Pre Natal and Post Natal.

The behavior you must have is:

I select Natal => Only the rows with Natal appear

Select Natal and Pre Natal => appear only rows with Pre Natal and Natal

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution:

```
return '^'+$(this).text()+'$';
```